# AWS Lambda + API Gateway "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Tags: kotlin, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I am using AWS Lambda with API Gateway. I have used the same setup with other projects that have worked fine. The only differences are I am using Kotlin instead of Go and the Serverless Framework. I have 2 endpoints, one to get a list of flavors the other to add a flavor. Both use the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. For the front-end I am using React and making http calls to the api with axios. Getting the list of flavors works fine, but when I try to add a flavor with that endpoint I get the `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error. The weird part is that when I make the same request with the API Gateway test feature it says that the header is present and everything works. I have also tried to make the same request with Intellij http calls and curl both of which also worked.

I hope that someone else has had this issue before, thanks for your time!

Comment: So you mean GET request works but POST/PUT is not working?

Comment: Exactly, and they both have the header. Also to add when I go to the network tab and look at the request the header is not there but like I said in the post it is there with everything else I have e tried to use to make the request.

Comment: In the post request path, do you have parameters? E.g /example/1/create if so try without any params  just to evaluate

Comment: I do not have any path params

Comment: I am still unable to explain what was happening here but I moved on to trying to add some auth since I was so stumped by this. While doing that I messed something up and had to delete my api-gateway api and remake all of the functions. After doing so my POST started to work exactly as expected.